# Java - Arraylist Minor Distance Prints

Tags: java, arraylist, distance, transport

I'm currently doing a project for college and i hit a speed bump 
The project is about transportation where i need to input two coordinates lets say x and y and then print them by order for this i have calculated the distance but i need to print all the value in the arraylist and i'm currently stuck the code so far is this where i can get the diference between the two value to see which is smaller

```
 public String ClosestGoods(int x,int y){`
            int near=0;
            int vdistance=0
            int result=0;
            int closest=0;
            String resultgoods = "";

            near=x+y;
            Iterator<Goods>listgoods = goods.iterator();

            while (listgoods.hasNext()) {

                Goods listg = listgoods.next();

                vdistance=listg.getX()+listg.getY();

                if(near <= vdistance){
                    result = (vdistance - near);
                }
                if(near >= vdistance){
                    result = (near - vdistance);
                }

                if(closest<result){
                    closest=result;
                    resultgoods += listg.toString() + "\n";
                }

            }               
            return resultgoods;          
}
```

Can anyone please give me a hand and tell me what am i missing
Thank to Everyone who replies beforehand

Update 1 - Requested by aviad
By order i mean the shortest distance from the request point gets printed first, then the second and so on until it the end.

Comment: what do you mean 'print them by order'? what are 'ordering rules'? example of 3 points would help. Also, what is not working?

Comment: Diff between two numbers (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is sqrt((x1-x2)^2 +(y1-y2)^2)) not (x2+y2) - (x1+y1)